# How to create a mysql kubernetes service with a locally mounted data volume?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, docker-for-mac, persistent-volumes

I should be able to mount a local directory as a persistent volume data folder for a mysql docker container running under minikube/kubernetes.

I don't have any problem achieving a shared volume running it with Docker directly, but running it under kubernetes, I'm not able to

```
osx 10.13.6
Docker Desktop Community version 2.0.0.2 (30215)
Channel: stable
0b030e17ca
Engine 18.09.1
Compose: 1.23.2
Machine 0.16.1
Kubernetes v1.10.11
minikube version: v0.33.1
```

Steps to reproduce the behavior

```
install docker-for-mac and enable kubernetes
```

create a directory on the mac to be shared as the persistent volume storage, e.g.

```
sudo mkdir -m 777 -p /Users/foo/mysql
```

deployment.yml

```
# For use on docker for mac
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: localstorage
provisioner: docker.io/hostpath
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
  hostPath:
    # this is the path on laptop? 
    path: "/Users/foo/mysql"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mysql-service
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-server
  labels:
    app: mysql-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql-server
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: ""
        - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "yes"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-pvc
          # this is the path on the pod container?
          mountPath: "/mnt/data"
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pvc
```

I can start up the pod, connect through mysql client, create a database, but when pod shuts down, the data does not persist and there is nothing written to the mounted data folder

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yml
kubectl port-forward mysql-server-6b64c4545f-kp7h9 3306:3306
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root
    mysql> create database foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| foo                |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

....

deleting the deployment:

```
kubectl delete sc "localstorage" 
kubectl delete persistentvolume "mysql-pv" 
kubectl delete persistentvolumeclaim "mysql-pvc" 
kubectl delete service "mysql-service" 
kubectl delete deployment.apps "mysql-server" 
kubectl delete events --all
```

re-create and connect again as above

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Did you created a persistent volume?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi . Please refer to the section above: create a directory on the mac to be shared as the persistent volume storage and also the deployment.yml.  Please tell me if there is some other step you feel is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You must create a [**Persistent Volume**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), defining the [**Storage Class as Local**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local), then map it to local path.

Creating Storage Class

**storage-class.yml**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Then run `kubectl create -f storage-class.yml`

Creating Persistent Value

**pv-local.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - cka
```

Create persistent volume running `kubectl create -f pv-sdc.yml`

A last, create persistent volume claim

**pvc1.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Create persistent volume clain running `kubectl create -f pvc1.yml`

To list persistent values run `kubectl get pv`. You should see some output like

```
NAME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS    REASON    AGE
local-pv       10Gi      RWO            Retain           Available             local-storage             10s
```

The persistent volume will be available as soon as a node uses it.

[This](https://serverascode.com/2018/09/19/persistent-local-volumes-kubernetes.html) post may help you little bit more.

Comment: Sorry @slashdottir, I miss some step. To create Persistent Volume Clain. Just updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Mauro for this info, however, when I apply your solution, I still have the same issue in that the data does not persist, also nothing is written to the local volume:  https://pastebin.com/f9C9anD5

Comment: In `volume_mounts`, is the pod path. In your **pv-local.yaml** file you did not defined the `local` > `path: /path/from/you/machine` guideline.

Comment: Thank you Mauro, I corrected that info, still getting errors though: https://pastebin.com/CRrURGin

Comment: How would you solve an issue when replica scaler provisions a pod on a different node where this local storage is not available? Based on my understanding, you should use Node Affinity which ensures that pod is started on required node.